# Combine Parent-Child Rows - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parent-child

lI am trying to flatten/combine rows from a table with a parent-child hierarchy. I'm trying to identify the beginning and the end of each 'link' - so if **a** is linked to **b**, **b** is linked to **c**, and then **c** is linked to **d**, I want the output to link **a** to **d**.

I'm trying my best to avoid using a procedure with loops, so any advice would be much appreciated!

The original dataset and the required output is as follows:

```
personID | form    | linkedform   
---------|---------|---------
    1    |    a    |   b
    1    |    b    |   c
    1    |    c    |   d
    1    |    d    |   NULL
    2    |    e    |   f
    2    |    f    |   g
    2    |    g    |   NULL
    2    |    h    |   i
    2    |    i    |   NULL
    3    |    j    |   NULL
    3    |    k    |   l
    3    |    l    |   NULL
```

Desired output:

```
personID | form    | linkedform   
---------|---------|---------
    1    |    a    |   d
    2    |    e    |   g
    2    |    h    |   i
    3    |    j    |   NULL
    3    |    k    |   l
```

Each personID can have multiple links, and a link can be made of just one or multiple forms.

Comment: This looks like a simple groupby using the max function.

EDIT: On second thought, maybe not...

Comment: It appears to me you want the leaf nodes of all forms for each person this is handled with a recursive CTE in tSQL.  @user2366842 I don't think so.  Look at personID 3 or 2 where multiple paths exist.

Comment: Here's and [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9100c/2) showing a recursive CTE. From here the desired output is but a few steps away.

Comment: Is the path always linear, or can it branch out some? I mean, could a link directly to both b and c, and from there have multiple end points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- use a recursive cte to build the hierarchy
-- start with [linkedform] = null and work your way up
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  *, [form] AS [root],
            1 AS [Level]
    FROM    Table1
    WHERE   [linkedform] IS NULL
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT  t1.*,
            [root],
            [Level] + 1
    FROM    Table1 t1
    JOIN    cte ON cte.form = t1.linkedform
)
-- level 1 will be the last element, use row_number to get the first element
-- join the two together based on last and first level, that have the same personid and root ([linkedform] = null)
SELECT  cte.personId,
        cte2.form, 
        cte.form
FROM    cte
        JOIN (  SELECT  *, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personId, [root] ORDER BY Level DESC) Rn 
                FROM    cte) cte2 
            ON cte2.Rn = cte.Level 
                AND cte2.personId = cte.personId
                AND cte2.root = cte.root
WHERE   cte.[Level] = 1
ORDER BY cte.personId, cte2.form
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this (and for the helpful extra commentary). Much appreciated!